# External CSS file isn't loaded

Tags: theming

I am trying to load an external CSS file to globally effect my website.

I have tried the following in `/core/themes/olivero/olivero.libraries.yml` but no change occured after cache rebuild.

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      css/base/fonts.css: {}
      css/base/base.css: {}
      css/base/utility.css: {}
      css/base/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPOSITORY/main/website/style.css: { type: external, minified: false}
```

Removing `css/base/` from before the URL doesn't matter.

Why does the external CSS file isn't loaded?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! There is documentation about this on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml#external

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188377/how-can-i-add-an-external-cdn-css-style-sheet-to-a-theme

Comment: I doubt it's a dupe because I don't use any CDN.

Comment: Using a CDN does not make any difference. Drupal does not handle CDN URLs differently from other external URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```css
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      css/base/fonts.css: {}
      css/base/base.css: {}
      css/base/utility.css: {}
      css/base/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPOSITORY/main/website/style.css: { type: external, minified: false}
```

Should be this:

```css
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      css/base/fonts.css: {}
      css/base/base.css: {}
      css/base/utility.css: {}
      //raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPOSITORY/main/website/style.css: { type: external, minified: false}
```

Make sure you clear the registry when you're done. If it doesn't load, look at the HTML source, and show us what is being loaded.

Comment: From `Developer tools >> Network >> CSS`, this file, alongside other CSS files from Drupal itself, is now being loaded (thereofre I gladly accepted the answer). But for some reason the CSS in that particular file, which is `* {display: none !important;}` doesn't effect the website at all (after cache rebuild from Drush), i.e. it doesn't override all Drupal-original CSS files, those from core, and those from Asset Injector module.

Comment: Sounds like a different problem.